# Is this a composition of scalar fields? Meaning of $(\phi(x,y,z,t),x,y,z)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

In the following I'm interested in the mathematics, not the physical representation.

The [diffusion equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_equation#Statement) is 
$$
\frac{\partial \phi(\mathbf{r},t)}{\partial t}=\nabla \cdot [D(\phi,\mathbf{r})\nabla\phi(\mathbf{r},t)]
$$

Here $\phi$ and $D$ are multivariable functions. 
I think the explicit form of $D(\phi,\mathbf{r})$ is
$$
D(\phi,\mathbf{r})=D(\phi(\mathbf{r},t),\mathbf{r})=D(\phi(x,y,z,t),x,y,z)
$$
But what does $D(\phi(x,y,z,t),x,y,z)$ mean, is it a function composition?

$\phi(\mathbf{r},t)$ is $\mathbb R^4 \rightarrow \mathbb R$, but what is $D$?

Comment: The diffussion term $D$ would be also a function from $\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @VladimirVargas:  $D$ is a function from a subset $U \subset \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$.  $\phi$ is generally a scalar *density*, so $D$ only depends directly on two variables.

Comment: I added the pde tag to your post.

Comment: @ Donsert : If you are interested in the mathematics, $(\phi(x,y,z,t),x,y,z))$ is a non-sens because mismatched parentheses. If you are interested in physics, an attempt can be made to fix it.

Comment: @JJacquelin Hi! Can you clarify what you mean with "non-sens" and "an attempt can be made to fix it"? English is not my native language, so I don't really grasp what you mean.

Comment: Not really important : I only wanted to draw your attention on your writing : $(\phi(x,y,z,t),x,y,z))$ which is meaningless, due to a mismatch of parentheses and that you should correct it.

Answer (score 0):

The diffusion equation as given at the linked location is
$$
\frac{\partial \phi(\mathbf{r},t)}{\partial t}=\nabla \cdot [D(\phi,\mathbf{r})\nabla\phi(\mathbf{r},t)]\ ,
$$
whereby the diffusion coefficient $D(\phi,{\bf r})$ depends on the momentary concentration $\phi$ at the location ${\bf r}$ (and not explicitly on $t$, as you wrote).

The quantity $\nabla\phi({\bf r},t)$ is the momentary spacial gradient field of $\phi$. This field is scaled  with the factor $D(\phi,{\bf r})$, whereby a new field, say $\Psi({\bf r},t)$, results. The operation $\nabla\cdot$ then takes the divergence of this field $\Psi$ , so that we obtain a scalar function depending on ${\bf r}$ and $t$.

The left hand side of the diffusion equation just computes the time derivative of $\phi$ at each point ${\bf r}$, and is also a scalar function of ${\bf r}$ and $t$.